# Want to show the record as mentioned in attached image from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show the records from two tables in same format as shown in the attached image link. please help how to show this either through PHP or MYSQL.

[Want to show the record as mentioned in attached image from two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2AD0.png)

```
<?php 
$con = @mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password);
mysql_select_db( $mysql_db_database);

$res = mysql_query("SELECT  assembly, COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2013')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained ELSE NULL END ) AS '2013',
COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2014')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained   ELSE NULL END ) AS '2014',
COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2015')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained   ELSE NULL END ) AS '2015',
COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2016')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained   ELSE NULL END ) AS '2016',
COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2017')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained   ELSE NULL END ) AS '2017',
COUNT( CASE WHEN (`elect`.election_year =  '2018')  THEN  `tbl_observer_stats`.male_observers_trained   ELSE NULL END ) AS '2018'
FROM elect LEFT JOIN tbl_observer_stats ON (elect.id=tbl_observer_stats.election_id)  GROUP BY assembly") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<table width="812" class="listing resultList resultList--tbl_election" border="1">
        <tr class="table-headings">
        <th class="row-actions-header" width="157" rowspan="3"><div align="left"><strong>Assembly</strong></div></th>
        <th height="43" colspan="14" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>Number of Observers Trained</strong></div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-headings">
                <th colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2013</strong></div></th>
                <th width="74" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2014</strong></div></th>
                <th width="74" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2015</strong></div></th>
                <th width="74" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2016</strong></div></th>
                <th width="74" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2017</strong></div></th>
                <th width="114" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>2018</strong></div></th>
                <th width="141" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>Total</strong></div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-headings">
                <th width="30" height="43" class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th width="16" class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
       </tr> 

      <?php  while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {?>  

      <tr class="table-headings">
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td> 
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td> 
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <?php  }?>

        </table>
```

Comment: You should do that then!

Comment: I tried through mysql query but didn't get success

Comment: What have you done so far to try it yourself?

Comment: @verhie, I have tried this query, but we cannot as we cannot get two fields in THEN condition, so this is not fullfil my requirements, also it doesn't show the record in the format as mentioned in attached image link. I am not able to post code in comments section

Comment: What? You need to show us more information because we can't just spit SQL to match your requirements

Comment: .... OK... But what have you tried in terms of displaying the resultant data? What's your actual question?

Comment: Yeah well no one here has access to your database, and I'm sure no one here is going to take the time to replicate your database just to give you your answer. If you wanted to show us what you've tried with that query and your code to display it  and how it's not working we might be able to help you

Comment: I see a bunch of non-breaking spaces...

Comment: Yeah no, you're still not going anything with the result from the query..

Comment: Column `male_observers_trained` suggests that you don't want to `COUNT()` (rows) but get `SUM()` (of their values) right? Which table `assembly` belong to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php 
$con = @mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password);
mysql_select_db( $mysql_db_database);


$res = mysql_query("select
a.assembly,
a.election_year,
COUNT(b.male_observers_trained) as male,
COUNT(b.female_observers_trained) as female
FROM elect a
LEFT JOIN tbl_observer_stats b ON (a.id=b.election_id)
GROUP BY a.assembly, a.election_year") or die(mysql_error());

$ar = array();
$years = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
  /* fetch into multi array */
  $ar[$result['assembly']][$result['election_year']] = array('male'=>$result['male'], 'female'=>$result['female']);
  /* make array of distinct years */
  $years[$result['election_year']] = $result['election_year'];
}
mysql_free_result($res);
sort($years);

?>

<table width="812" class="listing resultList resultList--tbl_election" border="1">
        <tr class="table-headings">
        <th class="row-actions-header" width="157" rowspan="3"><div align="left"><strong>Assembly</strong></div></th>
        <th height="43" colspan="<?php echo count($years)*2 ?>" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>Number of Observers Trained</strong></div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-headings">
              <?php
              foreach($years as $year){
                echo '<th colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>' . $year . '</strong></div></th>';
              }
              ?>

                <th width="141" colspan="2" class="row-actions-header"><div align="center"><strong>Total</strong></div></th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="table-headings">
              <?php
              foreach($years as $year){
                echo ' <th width="30" height="43" class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
                <th width="16" class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>';
              }
                ?>

       <th width="30" height="43" class="row-actions-header">Male Observer</th>
       <th width="16" class="row-actions-header">Female Observer</th>
       </tr> 

      <?php

      $colSum = array();

      foreach($ar as $assembly => $data){
        $total_male = 0;
        $total_female = 0;
        echo '<tr class="table-headings"><td class="field-content resultListCell">' . $assembly . '</td>';
        foreach($years as $year){
          echo '
          <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . $data[$year]['male'] . '</td>
          <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . $data[$year]['female'] . '</td>';
        $total_male += $data[$year]['male'];
        $total_female += $data[$year]['female'];

        $colSum[$year]['male'][] = $data[$year]['male'];
        $colSum[$year]['female'][] = $data[$year]['female'];

        }
        echo '
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . $total_male . '</td> 
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . $total_female . '</td>
      </tr>';

       }

       echo '<tr class="table-headings"><td class="field-content resultListCell">TOTAL</td>';

       $totalSum = array();
        foreach($years as $year){
          echo '
          <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . array_sum($colSum[$year]['male']) . '</td>
          <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . array_sum($colSum[$year]['female']) . '</td>';
          $totalSum['male'][] = array_sum($colSum[$year]['male']);
          $totalSum['female'][] = array_sum($colSum[$year]['female']);

        }
        echo '
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . array_sum($totalSum['male']) . '</td> 
      <td class="field-content resultListCell">' . array_sum($totalSum['female']) . '</td>
      </tr>';
       ?>

        </table>
```

Comment: forgive me for not addressing the mysql_ deprecated thing

Comment: its ok, but it is not showing assembly and also the total count is not populating in its own td. can you please modify the code a little bit more to fulfill my requirements as mentioned in the attached image please to show the assembly as well.

Comment: Dude, can you put in a little effort yourself?

Comment: @Muzafar, made some changes to it. Thank me later

Comment: Of couse I am thankful to you and will give u a+, I am not getting the result. there is my mistake from my side. it should not count the male and female, it should retrieve all assembly, election year, male and female observers, and after this sum up male and female observers against each year and assembly.  I am attaching the records in database with me, you will get idea. i think query should not group and v group assembly and year through php code. please if u could look at it. please

Comment: please check the image link at top in question with name Data in Database.

Comment: Thank you @verhie, I did it, I have sum up the observers against assembly and year. Thank you so much once again for your kind support. a+ is yours. looking for your skype.

Comment: Sorry @verhie, I am trying to up vote, but as i am new in stachoverflow and not much reputation, thats why I am not able to up vote. I don't know how to give a+ :(